# How to integrate Firebase notifications in custom ViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate Firebase FCM into my iOS app. Following their tutorial, I'm supposed to do this in the `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
                [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
      options: authOptions,
      completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    
    return true
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the user will be prompted to Allow/Deny access to notifications right when the app launches. According to Apple, it's a good practice to explain to your users why they need the notifications so they can better decide whether to enable them or not, and that's what I want to do. I want to create a custom view controller where I first explain why I need notifications and then I ask them if they want to enable or not. The problem with that is that I can't do `application.registerforRemoteNotifications()` from my VC, because I don't have access to the application in there. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can call at any time in your application using shared application object:

```
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```